# Co-index of a Space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

I am going through [this](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyushujm/59/2/59_2_321/_pdf/-char/ja) paper by Tanaka. But I got stuck at the Proposition 2.4 given below as well.[image]

Here he doesnot provide any proof rather just refers to Theorem 6.6 of another [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-66/issue-6/Fixed-point-free-involutions-and-equivariant-maps/bams/1183523747.full). Again given below [image]

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how the Proposition above, follows from Theorem below.

Can anyone provide any hints or suggestions.
They will be really appreciated.

thanks and Regards in advance